# p5js only drawing what's needed

Tags: p5.js

I'm looking for a way to limit what gets done in the draw loop.
I have a system where when I click, it add's a rect.
This rect then starts spawning circles that move.

since the rect does not change location, it isn't ideal to redraw it in every frame.

Is there a way to put the rects on a different layer of sorts, or is there another mechanism that I can use to limit the rect-drawing without impeding the circle-drawing?

I've tried with createGraphic to make a background with the rects, but I can't make the 'foreground' where the circles reside to be transparant.

Comment: Maybe show us a little code of what you have tried and what you want to achieve? I feel like this may be an unnecessary micro optimisation. I doubt having to redraw a rectangle is costly at all, and I'm sure the canvas has its own optimisations in place for when pixels aren't set to change!

Answer (score 0):

Curious about this I tried myself. My idea was simply grabbing the canvas and interacting with it regardless of p5.js.

My result was that the draw... in this case ***ctx.fillRect did not render on screen.***

***However the fillStyle was changed.***

Canvas is surprisingly efficient as well as WebGL and can handle the performance usually... unless you are rendering hundreds(mobile) to thousands(laptop/desktop) of objects.

I would have liked to have a better outcome but I think it was worthwhile posting what I had tried and my outcome nonetheless.

```
//P5 Setup
function setup(){
  createCanvas(1500, 750);
  background('rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)');
  stroke(255);
  fill(255)
  doNonP5Drawing();
}

//Render
function draw(){
   background(0);
   frame();
}

function doNonP5Drawing(){
    let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillStyle="red";
    ctx.fillRect(canvas.innerWidth/2 - 100,canvas.innerHeight/2 - 100,200,200);
}
```